# Solving a mixture of exponential and trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $x$ $$e^{\cot ^2 x}+\sin ^2 x-2\cos ^2 2x+4=4\sin x$$ It looks like I need to find the ranges of both the sides... But i am getting left side greater than $3$ and right side less than $4$. Some other things I might be missing. Thanks.

Comment: $x=\pi/2$ works.

Comment: I want the method

Comment: Putting values might work for you, but they don't for me.

Comment: This is a transcendental equation; so there may not be an algebraic process to find all solutions.  The exponential and trig functions are not very compatible (over reals), so I looked for a solution with $\cot^2 x=0$.  Only one of $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$ satisfies the equation.  Perhaps you can use the Mean Value Theorem to show that the solution is unique in $[0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Study the function $f(x)=e^{\cot ^2 x}+\sin ^2 x-2\cos ^2 2x+4$ and show than $f(x)=4$ is the minimum for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$

Compare with the maximum of $g(x)=4\sin(x)$ which maximum is g(x)=4 for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$

$f(x)\geq 4$ and $g(x)\leq 4$ So, when are they equal ?